# Open VPN - TAP V TUN

Tags: router, vpn

I have a ASUS RT N66U router that has OPEN VPN built in. I ideally want it to transmit an internet connection as if it where on my home network and be able to see network drives.

Using the TUN protocol I am able to get a Public IP address as if I were on my home network but it is on a different subnet so cannot see network drive.

Using the TAP protocol I am unable to get a Public IP address as if I were on my home network but I am on the same subnet with the local IP that allows me to see the network drive.

Is there a way to bridge these two set ups so I am able to achieve both?

Euan

Comment: Unfortunately, questions  about consumer grade equipment are off topic here. You can ask them on [su].